What if type Ia supernovae were mostly merging white dwarfs? Would that affect using them as a standard candle?
I have seen articles such as this one: https://www.aanda.org/articles/aa/full_html/2012/10/aa18966-12/aa18966-12.html
talking about this alternative way of creating a type Ia supernova. I even saw one that I haven't been able to find again saying that it may be most of them. I haven't found a discussion yet as to how this would affect using them as a standard candle and thus measurement of the Hubble constant and dark energy.

The Wikipedia article on the Type Ia supernova is pretty good, with over 60 cited articles, although many of those papers are >20 years old. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_Ia_supernova#Double_degenerate_progenitors doesn't mention what proportion of Ia supernovae are suspected of being double progenitor events, but some of the cited papers might.

The way this question is phrased seems to be "If 1a SN are not standard candles, would that affect using them as standard candles?"  To which the answer is rather obvious.  The question that Rob has found seems to be closely related, and has a good answer.
